# SQL Server not recognised after hosting the website

Tags: asp.net, web-hosting

I have hosted a website on `somee.com` and I'm getting the error which says that it is not able to connect to the sql server.
The web.config has the connectionstring as

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="RegConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Can anybody let me know the changes I have to make to get this working?

P.S. I have uploaded the database in App_Data folder.

Comment: Your connection string is pointing to a local address that can't be reached from the server.

Comment: @GarrisonNeely What should I change it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection string still pointing to your local SQL server and even it is local database of your system.

You have to modify your connection strig before publishing the site to the external server/ hosted server.
Change the whole connection string and put below properties within it.

Data Source=value; Initial Catalog=value; User ID = value; Password = value;

Here Data Source will be your SQL Server IP address or URL.

Here Initial Catalog will be your Database name.

You have to put User ID and Password which you are using to your SQL Server (Not Local)

Comment: I'm using windows authentication, should I change it to sql server authentication?

Comment: Yes of-course. Windows authentication scope is limited to local server only.Use SQL Server authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Lose this AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf I have never used it

Try these name value pairs

Data Source=value; Initial Catalog=value; User ID = value; Password = value;

Comment: what should be the value for Data source?

Comment: Data source is nothing but its your server name. It may be server ip address or URL.